# Can I debug node.js applications in Sublime 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, sublimetext2

Is this the right IDE for node.js or it's just a fast text editor? Can you guys suggest which IDE should be used for node.js?

Comment: Its not an IDE and there is no true debugger for node.js other than just running the node application. There is JSLint which will validate your javascript code.

Comment: Why not just use node-inspector? What do you use to debug your client-side javascript?

Comment: @pattmorter isn't [this](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) a Node debugger? Sure looks like it to me...

Comment: @MattDMo a very basic one.

Answer (score 13):

Using the Chrome Browser with [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) has been very valuable for debugging node.js applications.

Comment: This is the better answer

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft just released a new free & cross-platform text editor called Visual Studio Code, with built-in Node.js debugging capabilities that looks very exciting - https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Great info about the tool, never knew Microsoft released something like this! Thanks and the tool does exactly what is mentioned.

Comment: As a Sublime user trying out VS Code - I find it frustratingly unuseable.

Comment: Just noting that this doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: but this is about Sublime, and VS code doesn't really work like sublime.

Answer (score 6):

WebStorms is an IDE with a very strong debugger for Node.js built in. It's just like the traditional debuggers in Eclipse or .NET.
It also has good support for things like CoffeeScript, etc.
http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should consider using a modern, open source text editor called [Brackets](http://brackets.io), which has extension called Node.js Debugger.

To start using it first you'll need to install it from Brackets Extensions Manager. Then start your script with node `--debug-brk yor-script.js` or `node --debug your-script.js`

Go into Brackets and click on `Debug -> Node.js Debugger` or use `Ctrl-Shift-I`

More information available on the [github of the extension](https://github.com/TheBenji/brackets-node-debugger).

Comment: node: [DEP0062]: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` and `node --inspect-brk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a new build system for sublime 2 you can run it with the ctr-B command. 
See: [Build Systems](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the node.js plugin for eclipse which allows you to build node.js projects. I haven't used it in a while now but as far as I know you can just debug like normal using that.

You could give it a shot anyway, here's the link:

http://www.nodeclipse.org/